# Библиотеки, оптимизация и соглашения о вызове

Tags: c++, c, windows, передача-параметров

Для примера рассмотрим винду.

Как известно, транслятор может передавать параметры в функции через регистры, а может через стек. Когда весь проект транслируется с одинаковыми ключами трансляции, то все понятно. Но, например, в проекте есть библиотека *.lib, которая принимает параметры некоторых функций через регистры, а весь проект принимает параметры функций через стек. Как транслятор поймет, что некоторые библиотечные функции надо вызвать по-другому?

Comment: Как транслятор поймет, что некоторые библиотечные функции надо вызвать по-другому - никак, если об этом не сказано в `*.h` файле

Comment: Теоретически.. некоторые версии (фирмы) с++ зашивают в сигнатуру тип вызова - тогда они возможно (не проверял) поймут по-сигнатуре, в рамках когда транслятор и компилятор одной и той же версии. Но практически - нельзя вызвать функцию если она не обьявлена, а при обьявлении - вы задаёте явно или неявно соглашение о вызове. Поэтому на практике без преобразования `lib -> h` ничего не выйдет.

Comment: Поэтому для lib-функций (возможно не для всех) существует возможность "перепутать" сигнатуру и получить сбой.

Comment: @nick_n_a То есть получается, что прототип функции однозначно определяет соглашения о вызове для данного транслятора. И никакими ключами трансляции (в том числе ключами оптимизации) это нельзя изменить.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, раз уж мы на примере винды, то для msvc можно определить соглашение вызова по умолчанию https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gd-gr-gv-gz-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Comment: Это тут случае когда ногу отрывает целиком.

Comment: зато нога будет сложена в стек в нужном порядке)

Comment: "Для примера рассмотрим винду."? Каким образом в вопрос о компиляторах вдруг попала "винда"? При чем здесь она?

Comment: @AnT Просто я в основном работаю под виндой и примеры желательно тоже приводить из мира винды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способ передачи параметров и прочие детали соглашения о вызовах должен быть однозначно понятен компилятору из объявления функции.

Если библиотека была странслирована тогда, когда компилятор делал другие выводы о соглашениях о вызовах на основе имеющегося объявления библиотечной функции, то в общем случае такую библиотеку будет невозможно использовать.

В некоторых случаях объявления функций для "нового" компилятора можно подогнать так, чтобы они порождали правильные вызовы для "старого" кода. Хрестоматийный пример - переход стандартной библиотеки языка C с K&R объявлений на современные объявления с прототипами, вследствие чего прототипы стандартных функций подогнаны под K&R соглашения о вызовах: все объявления параметров "классических" функций сделаны с учетом default argument promotions, т.е. не используют типов `char`, `short` и `float`.

Comment: Разве ABI не определяется архитектурой именно для того, чтобы все компиляторы пользовались одинаковым соглашением для вызовов?